# Rails, Heroku, S3, and static resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I am working on a Rails web application, running on a Heroku stack, that handles looking after some documents that are attached to a Rails database object. i.e. suppose we have an object called `product_i` of class/table `Product/products`, and `product_i_prospectus.pdf` is the associated product prospectus, where each product has a single prospectus.

Since I am working on Heroku, and thus do not have root access, I plan to use Amazon S3 to store the static resource associated with `product_i`. So far, so good.

Now suppose that `product_i_attributes.txt` is also a file I want to upload, and indeed I want to actually fill out information in the `product_i` object (i.e. the row in the table corresponding to `product_i`), based on information in the file `product_i_attributes.txt`.

In a sentence: I want to create, or alter, database objects, based on the content of static text files uploaded to my S3 bucket.

I don't actually have to be able to access them once they are in the bucket strictly speaking, I just need to create some stuff out of a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar with csv files.  I would not try to process the file directly at upload as it can be resource intensive.

My solution was to upload the file to s3 and then call a background job method(delayed_job, resque, etc.) that processed the csv after upload.  You could then call a delete after the job processed to remove the file from s3 if you no longer needed it after processing.

For Heroku this will require that you add a worker (if you don't already have one) to process the background jobs that will process the text files.

Comment: thanks for the response, and your approach is exactly the one I want to implement. Could you direct me to any resources that you used, as conceptually I get the task in hand, but I am a little stumped on where to start on processing the S3 file?

Comment: I'll look and see if I can find anything that I found helpful when I did S3 processing. Are you familiar with storing the S3 file?  You should first have a model i.e. TextFileUpload that has access to the S3 objects using paperclip, carrierwave, or something similar.

Comment: John, I am somewhat familiar with that. At the moment I am just treating that like a "black box" while I get my CSV processing stuff in place. But I know that I can access and manipulate files put in S3, and I do have a model for doing so. Anything you have would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [aws-sdk-for-ruby](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby) gem. This will allow you to access your S3 bucket.